# Add a custom header on request in a Django middleware

Tags: django, django-request

I want to implement a middleware in django, that will append a header on the request's existing headers, before the *get_response(request)* function.

Though, when trying like this:

```
request.headers['CUSTOM_HEADER'] = 'CUSTOM_VALUE'
```

I get an error: *'HttpHeaders' object does not support item assignment* 
Also in django's request (WSGIRequest), there is no add_headers function like the python's request module. 
Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could set an attribute on the `request` object itself, e.g. `request.CUSTOM = 'CUSTOM_VALUE`. This is what several [Django middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#attributes-set-by-middleware) do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a simple middleware as below, and put the path in the [**`MIDDLEWARE`** settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/).

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class CustomHeaderMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.META['HTTP_CUSTOM_HEADER'] = "CUSTOM VALUE"
```