# Django custom middleware not adding custom header

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

So I'm trying to add a custom header to every request in my Django app, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632988/add-a-custom-header-on-request-in-a-django-middleware) question, and my setup looks like this:

**middleware.py**:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class ReverseProxyLocalMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.META['User-Id'] = 1
```

**settings.py**:

```
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'myapp.middleware.ReverseProxyLocalMiddleware',
]
```

**views.py**:

```
class UserViewSet(
    viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin
):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.User.objects.active(dt=timezone.now())

    def list(self, request):
        user_id = request.META['User-Id']
        ...
```

However, anytime I try and access the new header in a test I get:

```
    def list(self, request):
>       user_id = request.META['User-Id']
E       KeyError: 'User-Id'
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are trying to put in META?

Comment: It was my (I'm guessing poor) understanding that this is how you added custom headers - is there another way I'm meant to do it?

Comment: I tried your example and it's working. Which views are you using?

Comment: Added the Django view.

Comment: Are you mixing drf viewsets and Django mixins?

Comment: The mixins are also drf

Comment: It still works fine, please create a repository where the problem can be reproduced and attach a link to the question, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out Django drops the header if it's not in the `HTTP_*_*` format, so the middleware must look like:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class ReverseProxyLocalMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request, user_id=1):
        request.META['HTTP_USER_ID'] = user_id
```