# Django computing variable vaue in custom middleware and passing to all view functions

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am using Django 3.2. I want to compute the value of variable and make that value available to all views in my project.

I have decided to use middleware - but it is not clear (yet), how I can make the value I computed in MyCustomMiddleware available in a view.

Here is my custom middleware class:

```
class MyCustomMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        mysecret_value = 4269  

        return response
```

After making the requisite modifications to the MIDDLEWARE section in `settings.py`, how do I acesss `mysecret_value` in my views?

#### myapp/views.py

```
def foobar(request):
    the_value = mysecret_value # <- how do I access the RHS variable?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632988/add-a-custom-header-on-request-in-a-django-middleware

Comment: I know you asked for access in the view, but just in case what you actually need is to have it in the template, what you want is a `context_processor` not a new middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middlewares run before views, so you can actually modify the `request` object:

```
class MyCustomMiddleware:
    ...
    def __call__(self, request):
        request.mysecret_value = 4269
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Then you can access this value from any view:

```
def foobar(request):
    the_value = request.mysecret_value
```