# React and Django CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

I have a React frontend app that needs to send a request to my Backend written in Django

My frontend and backend are now on the same domain but different subdomains.

But I'm getting some CORS problems, more specificly, CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing.
I found a lot of questions on stackoverflow on how you need to install django-cors-headers but it simply doesn't work for me.

my current backend configuration:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

**views.py (where I create the api)**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@xframe_options_exempt
def create_user_and_ci(request):
    try:
        # code to execute
        return Response({"status": "Succes"}, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except:
        return Response({"status": "Error"}, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

And then on my frontend I execute this:

```
    fetch("https://subdomain.mydomain/get/id", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Token mytoken`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        // Other possible headers
      }
    }).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

**UPDATE**

When I make the call without giving the headers, it works, problem is I need to send my token to my backend for validation

Comment: Did you install this package?  `pip install django-cors-headers`

Answer (score -1):

Foremost, this CORS error is due to the fact that your frontend is not on the same domain as your Django API/Backend, so all the Django responses need to contain the CORS related headers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

I found this post about adding a custom HTTP header with a middleware in Django, this might help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632988/add-a-custom-header-on-request-in-a-django-middleware).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip, I just made sure that both of them are on the same domain but I still get the error? they are on a different subdomain tho

Answer (score -2):

**Install this package:**

```
    pip install django-cors-headers 

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
http://127.0.0.1:3000, #For React Project
http://127.0.0.1:8000  #For Django Project
]
```

**In MiddleWare  add this in the list**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",]
```

Comment: Did that but doesn't work at all for some reason

Comment: @Yorbjörn, Can you show here  your settings.py please. How you managed it for cors-headers.  `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000"]`  Where is your API port?

Comment: I just updated my question, where I now set ```CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True``` which should mean that every domain is allowed? I also found out that it simply works when I remove the "headers" part in my request in the frontend. sadly the headers are needed to send my token with my request

Comment: @Yorbjörn , Please do that and check again.  `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
http://127.0.0.1:3000, #For React Project
http://127.0.0.1:8000  #For Django Project
]`